# Xubuntu 20.04 apparently has no PPT security option in BIOS for legacy boot on some computers

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub-legacy

I am trying to install Xubuntu 20.04 by cloning from a flash drive to my Dell Optiplex 7010 desktop and there is no PPT Security option in the BIOS under Security in either legacy or uefi mode so can't turn it off. Does Xubuntu 20.04 not work on some computers and this is a bug that needs to be fixed? I read there would be an update to fix this in the future. Xubuntu 19.10 installed by cloning from a flash drive worked good so something has changed in 20.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Through Xubuntu 19.10 we didn't need to create a bios boot partition but in 20.04 you need to create a 1023 MB /boot partition and then your ext4 partition. We don't make swap partitions any more because they wear out ssd drives and we have plenty of ram now. Now cloned drives of Xubuntu 20.04 boot with no problem.